R - Sum rows from different column based on condition in grouped values
I have a large dataset of different sites inside and out of Natura 2000 network.
An example:
df



Name
Total_Surface
N2000
SurfaceN2000




A
1
Yes
0.5


B
5
No
NA


C
11
No
NA


D
10
Yes
5



I want to have the sum of surfaces grouped by the N2000 factor (one total surface for "Yes", another for "No"). However, if the site is inside the N2000 network (N2000=Yes), I want to take the data from the column "SurfaceN2000".
How can I make a sum that depending on the N2000 factor it takes the values from Total_Surface or SurfaceN2000?
I know I could create a column with the sum of Total_Surface and another one with SurfaceN2000 but I was wondering if there was a more automatic solution.
I tried a number of things but they didn't work. The last thing I tried was
df %>% 
  group_by(N2000) %>%
  summarise(surface=
             case_when(N2000== "No" ~ sum(Total_Surface,na.rm = TRUE), 
                       N2000== "Yes" ~ sum(SurfaceN2000,na.rm = TRUE)))

I also tried with filter() or rbind() but it didn't work either.
I was expecting an output table like:



N2000
Surface




Yes
5.5


No
16



Thank you very much in advance! :)

Replace each instance of N2000 with first(N2000) since you only want one value.

Hello, sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly. I want to create a new data frame where I have the sum  of the surfaces inside a N2000 site (here 0.5+5) and the sum of all the surfaces outside N2000 (here N200=No; 11+5). As I don't have the "No" surfaces in the column "SurfaceN2000", I want to take the data from the column "Total_Surface" ONLY for when N2000=No and when N2000=Yes I want to take the data from "SurfaceN2000. Is that more clear? Thank you very much for your help!!

Consider pivoting your data (according to a more sophisticated rule than demonstatred here).
tidyr::pivot_longer(d0, cols = c(Total_Surface, SurfaceN2000)) |>
  dplyr::summarise(Surface = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .by = (c(N2000, name)))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  N2000 name          Surface
  <chr> <chr>           <dbl>
1 Yes   Total_Surface    11  
2 Yes   SurfaceN2000      5.5
3 No    Total_Surface    16  
4 No    SurfaceN2000      0  

You could add a filter to return the desired subset.

Data.
> dput(d0)
structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Total_Surface = c(1L, 
5L, 11L, 10L), N2000 = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), SurfaceN2000 = c(0.5, 
NA, NA, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


Thank you very much! I hadn't thought of doing it that way. It works!! :)

Something like this?
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(area = ifelse(N2000 == "Yes", SurfaceN2000, Total_Surface)) %>%
  summarise(surface = sum(area, na.rm = TRUE), .by = N2000)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  N2000 surface
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 No       16  
2 Yes       5.5


Thank you Friede for your feedback, I am just learning (and not too good at this), can you suggest me a better alternative to the ifelse and to the whole redundant structure I used? I agree on the fact that the question might be unclear, but I thought there could be a decent degree of probability that a chunk similar to the one I presented (although it can be improved) could probably work the way Lara intended

Hello, thank you very much for your comments and your help. I tried your suggestions but they didn't work, although I think you understood what I was aiming for :). I edited the post to try to better explain the desired output. I hope it's more clear. Thank you very much!!!

I think you will get more helpful answers if you also provide some example data (which can be run in R, not only a snapshot) :) Also, out of curiosity, can you elaborate more about what is not working about Friede's and my (clumsier) proposal? It seems to me that it does what you are looking for

Hello again! I don't know why, but I was having a "negative length vectors are not allowed" error with your solution and then my whole R sesion crashed and when I restarted it, your solution worked!! Fried's solution gives a column of NA (and as I don't understand very well his code I don't know exactly why is that^^"). Thank you very much to both of you!!
